# How to use React BluePrint components with TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, blueprint

I am trying to use React and blueprint with tsx files

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from "@blueprintjs/core"

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
       return <Button intent="success" text="button content" />
    }
}

export default App;
```

The file is named as App.tsx. It throws error as:

> JSX element class does not support attributes because it does not have a 'props' property.ts(2607)
>   (alias) class Button
>   import Button

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Why should some one give negativevotes to this. i honestly dont know how to solve this problem

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I'm having the exact same error right now

Comment: no i was nit able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

you should define a `props` and `state` from `App`(you could simply pass {})

```
export class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> { }
```

using `<App />`

Or you want to define your `props`

```
export class App extends React.Component<{ name: string, age: number }, {}> { }
```

using `<App name="Join" age="22" />` 
Note these are object type not value.
To tell thar App will be able to recieve a props with `name, age`

Comment: but here i dont have props for the App, i am trying to use the blueprint button with the intent and text buttons